# Asynchronous Web Service in WPF

Tags: wpf, webserver

Iam developing WPF application and consume web service. Every 5 min I need to call web service and display data in WPF form. which one is better to use in web service (synchronous  or Asynchronous). Plz hel me in this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you need to handle user input and updates from the web service at the same time. If you call the web service on the same thread as the UI you will block the user from using the form.

If you move the call to the web service to an other thread that problem could be solved. Using an Asynchronous web service proxy does that for you.

Just make sure you do not block the user.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement your suggestion either by using Asynchronous web service call or backgroundworker class.